# ng2-smart-table custom slider

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in Angular. I had an action column which has add update delete functionalities (which works fine, no issue with this).

in the first column( check the picture below) I have a column called "Status" where the user can enable/disable a job in the Backend. I want to create a Slider below Column Status name (highlighted below, at filter position) where the user can enable/disable all jobs.

How will I achieve this? I tried to override the "Add New" button to achieve what I need, but it didn't work.

Note: I am using a child component to render the slider for each row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can utilize the Custom property in the Table Settings like this

```
Status: {
            'title': 'Status',
            type: 'custom',
            filter: false,
            renderComponent: StatusComponent,
            valuePrepareFunction: (value, row, cell) => {
                return row;
            },
```

Comment: You need to create a new component called StatusComponent in which you will put the Status slider and other functionalities

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already implemented the code you suggested to render a slider for each and every row as you can see in the screenshot.but what I am trying to find out is: how to add a main slider on top of the rows slider. The new slider will switch on/off all other sliders. How can I add this in table settings. Thanks again.

Comment: Alright, I haven't really tried customizing the main column headers and after reading through the documentation https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation, I don't think we can. Best we can do to solve the problem I guess is to just make a slider/button outside the Table to deactivate all sliders, Best of luck!